# Powershell script to rename files

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a bunch of files that have names that start with numbers, may contain spaces and dashes after one of two numbers, then sometimes (sometimes not) have a space just before the first alpha character of the name I want to keep, i.e.:

2-01 Dazed And Confused.txt (I want to rename this to Dazed And Confused.txt)

Or

02 - Uncle Salty.txt (I want to rename this to Uncle Salty.txt)

Or

02-The Night Before.txt (I want to rename to The Night Before.txt)

Comment: list script would get a list of files from a directory & rename them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dir c:\tmp | % {
     mv $_.FullName $(Join-Path $_.Directory ($_.Name -replace "^([0-9\-\s]*)",'').Trim());
}
```

If you need to recursively process YourDirectory, add `-recurse` after `dir`.

Comment: This doesn't work on the second example. Try `^([0-9\-\s]*)` instead

Comment: This worked on about 95% of the 600+ files I needed renaming.  Did throw an error the first time I ran it on a subset of the files I wanted to rename about moving files into same folder but it did rename the files. The second time I ran the script on the whole set of files it did not give me an error.  Thank you, great script.

Comment: The [`Move-Item`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113350) and [`Rename-Item`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113382) cmdlets can accept the source directly from the pipeline and provide a new name using a script block: `dir | move-item -destination { $_.Name -replace '^([0-9\-\s]*)' }` or `dir | rename-item -newname { $_.Name -replace '^([0-9\-\s]*)' }`

Comment: @EmperorXLII you should post this as a separate answer as i believe it's superior in its comprehensibility and conciseness to any of the existing answers.

Answer (score 6):

The [`Move-Item`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113350) and [`Rename-Item`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113382) cmdlets can accept the source directly from the pipeline and provide a new name using a script block:

```
dir | Move-Item -Destination { $_.Name -replace '^([0-9\-\s]*)' }
```

or

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^([0-9\-\s]*)' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$re = '^\d+\s*-\d*\s*(.*)$'
$recurse = $false

Get-ChildItem "C:\some\folder" -Recurse:$recurse | ? {
  -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match $re
} | % {
  Move-Item $_.FullName (Join-Path $_.Directory $matches[1])
}
```

If you want the hyphen to be optional change the regular expression to `'^\d+\s*-?\d*\s*(.*)$'`.

If you want to recurse into subfolders change `$recurse` to `$true`.

Comment: This one changed most of the files but about 15% did not rename.

Comment: @user577651 What did the file names of these 15% look like?